# If a num is divisible by two number logic C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I'm trying to find out how the code would look if a number was divisible by two numbers. Example 15 is both divisible by both 3 and 5.

Then I would be able to say

```
Console.WriteLine("This Number is Divisible by 3 and 5!");
```

How do I going about coding that and where would I place it? Please help.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter A Number :");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (n % 3 == 0)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("This Number is Divisible by 3 ");

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This Number is Not Divisible by 3");

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to check that number is divisible by 3 and 5 or by any other numbers also? Or a specific range of numbers like 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Why can't you just, in your example, check if the number is divisible by 15? This question seems to be about math, not programming. Please be more specific about what you're having trouble figuring out.

Comment: to be more clear, if I enter a number like 9 I want it to say "this num is divisible by 3" if I enter a number like 10 I want it to say "this num is divisible by 5" and last if I enter a number like 15 I want it to say "this num is divisible by 3 and 5".

Comment: Do yourself a favor: search using your favorite search engine for the Fizz Buzz problem. You'll find hundreds of examples that do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter A Number :");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (n % 3 == 0)
            {
                if (n % 5 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This Number is Divisible by 3 and 5!");

                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\nThe number is divisible by 3 but not by 5");
                }
            }

            else if (n % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is divisible by 5 but not by 3");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThis Number is Not Divisible by 3 and 5!");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

Enter a number: 21

Number is divisible by 3 but not by 5

Comment: This code would not work because if you enter the number 10 it prints out Console.WriteLine("This Number is Not Divisible by 3 and 5");

Comment: @Kai working fine as u expected??

Comment: Thanks Manu looks like it's working great! The only thing is change printf to Console.WriteLine :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution on how you can do it:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter A Number :");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Number is Divisible by 3 and 5 ");

        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Number is Not Divisible by 3 and 5");

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: However I would still like the the individual Console.WriteLine("This Number is Not Divisible by 3"); or Console.WriteLine("This Number is Not Divisible by 5"); because what if I entered a number 9 or 10?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Simple Logic for you, Which will Print all Factors. By taking the advantages of `int.TryParse` for validating the input(if the input is not a number or convertible to an integer then it will show the invalid input message). Then it will iterate through the numbers up to half of the given number and collect those numbers which are divisible.

**Consider the code below:**

```
int numberInput;
List<int> factors = new List<int>();
Console.WriteLine("Enter A Number :");
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberInput))
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= numberInput/2; i++)
    {
        if (numberInput % i == 0)
        {
            factors.Add(i);
        }
    }
    if (factors.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is divisible by {1}", numberInput, String.Join(",",factors));
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number is Prime");
    }

}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This will Give output as

> `"15 is divisible by 3,5"` for an input `15`
>
> `"20 is divisible by 2,4,5,10"` for an input `20`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int n, c;
    c = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter A Number :");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    { 
    if (n%i==0)
    {
        c++;
        if(c==1)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("This Number is Divisible by "+i);
        }
        else
        {
        Console.Write(" and "+i);
        }               
    }
      }
```